# What is the time and space complexity of the following program? - leetcode 1291

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

[image]

Can somebody pls tell me what the time and space complexity of my answer is?

I think the time complexity is O(nlogn) assuming this is how long the sorted function takes. I'm also assuming that the double for loop takes constant O(1) time because the length of the numbers string does not change.

I think the space complexity is O(n) where n is the number of elements in our results array. But, I'm unsure of this answer.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class Solution(object):
    def sequentialDigits(self, low, high):
        """
        :type low: int
        :type high: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        numbers = "123456789" #every possible substring of this string represents the set of valid numbers that we can have
        
        results = []
        
        #get every substring from the 'number' string 
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            for j in range(i, len(numbers)):
                # sustring in range i to j
                subString = numbers[i:j+1]
                
                #convert it to an integer
                subString= int(subString)
                
                #if its within the required range, add it to our array
                if low<=subString<=high:
                    results.append(subString)
                    
        return sorted(results)
```

Comment: Worst case it will be O(n2) where n is length of number

Comment: @Ananth And O(81) is O(1). The inner loop body executes 45 times independent of input.

Comment: but the length n of the numbers string is constant? so why can't it be O(1)?

Comment: Hint: you can avoid the sort if you flip the order of the loops: first search for length 1 strings (starting from 1), then length 2 strings, etc.

Comment: Yes, the complexity is O(1) as it is pointed by @teekarna. I would advise not to use n to describe the length of the numbers string not to confuse it with the size of input which is also denoted by n. In your case the size of the input n is the value of high.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity of your algorithm is O(1). The big O notation is used to denote the *asymptotic upper bound* of an algorithm as the input size (n) tends to infinity. In this particular case, there are only a finite number of possible solutions (45) which your algorithm correctly finds. Therefore the worst-case running time (or memory consumption) does not depend on the inputs; you always need to loop over maximum 45 candidates.

Comment: Since the 45 possibles are known in advance, they could easily be hardcoded into a sorted list.  All that would remain is to determine the first and the last relative to `low` and `high`

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of **numbers** string depends on the order of input. The length would be **log<sub>10</sub>n**. So the time complexity from the loop will be **O( (log<sub>10</sub>n )<sup>2</sup>)**. And maximum length for the results array will be in length of numbers string squared so time complexity for the sorting will be **O( log<sub>10</sub>n( log( log<sub>10</sub>n ) )**. Overall time complexity will be **O( ( log<sub>10</sub>n)<sup>2</sup> + log<sub>10</sub>n( log( log<sub>10</sub>n ) ) )** which simplifies to **O( log<sub>10</sub>n( log( log<sub>10</sub>n ) ) )**.

Comment: The numbers string is hard coded to "123456789", so it has a fixed length of 9. It does not depend on input at all.